# ¿Como puedo enumerar campos con registros repetidos en otro campo SQL Server script?

Tags: sql-server, script, registro

**Tengo una tabla con algunos registros repetidos, pero necesito enumerar llenando el 3er campo con el numero de la repeticion. Mi tabla esta algo asi**

| ID | Pais | Orden |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mexico | NULL |
| 2 | Mexico | NULL |
| 3 | Mexico | NULL |
| 4 | Argentina | NULL |
| 5 | Argentina | NULL |
| 6 | Argentina | NULL |
| 7 | Argentina | NULL |
| 8 | EUA | NULL |
| 9 | EUA | NULL |
| 10 | Brazil | NULL |

**Necesito llenar el tercer campo que tengo en NULL con el numero de la repeticion y deberia quedar algo asi**

| ID | Pais | Orden |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Mexico | 1 |
| 2 | Mexico | 2 |
| 3 | Mexico | 3 |
| 4 | Argentina | 1 |
| 5 | Argentina | 2 |
| 6 | Argentina | 3 |
| 7 | Argentina | 4 |
| 8 | EUA | 1 |
| 9 | EUA | 2 |
| 10 | Brazil | 1 |

**si saben de alguna forma practica de hacerlo**
**PD: son aproximadamente 700 registros en la tabla**

Comment: Te sugiero que leas acerca de [ROW_NUMBER()](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) e intentes encontrar una solución por tu cuenta.